# In C#, how do I use Console.WriteLine method to write ALL columns from my SqlCommand

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I'm new to C# but have managed to piece together an SQLCommand  query. However , I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to display all columns. The below code is what i have currently (it successfully shows the first 5 columns):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} \t | {1} \t | {2} \t | {3} \t| {4} \t",
    reader[0], reader[1], reader[2], reader[3], reader[4]));
```

What is the simplest way to show ALL columns without having to list each one like I did above? Also, is there a way to specifically name the columns that i want to display? for example, the below successfully shows the "company" column but I cant figure out how to do multiple columns specifically. What if i wanted to show "company" and "FiscalYear"?:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader["Company"].ToString());
```

I researched this for about 2 hours but was unable to come up with a solution. thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is `reader` an instance of `SqlDataReader`?

Comment: yes. sorry about not specifying that. below is where I establish that: 
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `StringBuilder` to create the text in a loop

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
    sb.Append($"{reader[i]} \t |");
}
sb.Length -= 4; // Remove the last " \t |".
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

`sb.Append(something)` is more efficient than `s = s + something`, because string concatenations always create a new string object and copy the old string to the new one before appending something. Whereas the `StringBuilder` works with a buffer and can append several times until the buffer is full and must be resized.

The $ stands for string interpolation. These two lines are equivalent:

```
String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", a, b, c)
$"{a}, {b}, {c}"
```

Comment: could you explain why the below code doesn't show the company and fiscal year columns?  Console.WriteLine(reader["Company"],reader["FiscalYear"]);      if the company name is LWRV and the year is 2017 i would expect the output to look like LWRV  2017

Comment: Because the first parameter is supposed to be a format string and the following ones the arguments. Works the same as `String.Format`. You could write `Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader["Company"], reader["FiscalYear"]);`. In other words, in the code of your question, you could just drop the `Format.String` call inside the `Console.WriteLine`: `Console.WriteLine("{0} \t | {1} \t | {2} \t | {3} \t| {4} \t",
    reader[0], reader[1], reader[2], reader[3], reader[4]);`

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. Merry Christmas to me. thanks brother.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SqlDataReader's FieldCount property in a loop, like:

```
while (reader.Read())
    {
      for (int i=0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
      {
        Console.Write(reader[i] + ",");
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

I know this doesn't help you with your string.Format() statement where you have the number of fields hardcoded.  Not really trying to help you with the formatting here, just giving you a tip on how to access all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

If your `reader` variable is an instance of `SqlDataReader`, you could do something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    SqlDataReader reader = getDataReader();   \\Code that returns a data reader
    Console.WriteLine(createOutputString(reader));
}

private string createOutputString(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    //Create an array to hold all the values of the reader
    object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];

    //Fill the array with the values
    reader.GetValues(values);

    //Return a string with each value of the array separated by a delimiter
    return string.Join(" \t | ", values);
}
```